# How to correctly segue information from TableView to ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

I'm trying pass some information via a segue from a TableView to a ViewController.

Through my debugging I'm able to see that the ViewController reads the variable before it is set in the TableView. This results in a value of nil (it's an optional) instead of what I'm expecting, but if I go back to my tableView and select the value again, it will set itself correctly.

Do I need to somehow slow down the reading in viewDidLoad() or am I missing some basic part of segueing from the tableView? I'm mostly curious why the value is nil the first time, but works on the second.

The segue from the TableView:

```
// MARK: - Send information to the FBOSelector
// Send the fieldName the user selects
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! FBOSelectorViewController

let path = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
destination.fieldName = self.locations[(path?.row)!]

self.fetchFbos(self.locations[(path?.row)!])

}
```

Setting the values in the TableView that I will pull in the viewController:

```
// This is failing because the values are read in FBOSelector before they are set here
// Using the fieldname selected pass the rest of the information to FBOSelector
func fetchFbos(fieldName: String) {
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Airport/\(fieldName)/FBOs/Signature")

    ref.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        //           print(snapshot)
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            RegistrationsManager.sharedManager.activeReservation.firfullName = dictionary["fullname"] as? String
            // This will fire after the value in FBOSelector is read
            print("DELAYED SETTER")
            print(RegistrationsManager.sharedManager.activeReservation.firfullName)
        }
    })
}
```

In the TableView I am setting some labels with the value I set in the TableView but they return nil (the first time, if I go back and select them again they appear correctly)

```
func firebaseInfo() {
    self.fieldNameLabel.text = fieldName
    self.locationLabel.text = RegistrationsManager.sharedManager.activeReservation.firfullName
    //*** BUG IS HERE ***
    // On first click locationLabel is nil
//        print("DEBUG INFO")
        print(RegistrationsManager.sharedManager.activeReservation.firfullName)
}
```

And then I run it in viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    fboCollectionView.delegate = self
    fboCollectionView.dataSource = self
    fboCollectionView.pagingEnabled = true

    firebaseInfo()
}
```

Seems like a speed issue / concurrency problem to me? I've tried getting the value in the ViewController with a viewWillAppear (same issue) and using sleep() (no good because it stops all processing). Can someone point me in the right direction of a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is my method to achieve passing the data.

TableViewController

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let selectedIndexPath:NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        let genVC:genViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! genViewController
        genVC.selectedItem = myData[selectedIndexPath.row]

}
```

GenViewController

```
var selectedItem: NSManagedObject?
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   fetchData()
}
```

The `fetchData()` would be the code to pull the data from the database based on the index sent.

Answer (score 0):

Hey so I would try calling `fetchFbos(indexPath: indexPath)` in didSelectCellAtIndexPath and remove `self.fetchFbos(_:)` from `prepareForSegue`

The below `fetchFbos(indexPath: IndexPath)` will perform the segue after getting the new value from firebase.

```
func fetchFbos(indexPath: IndexPath) {
 let fieldName = self.locations[indexPath.row]
 let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Airport/\(fieldName)/FBOs/Signature")

ref.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
    //           print(snapshot)
    if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
        RegistrationsManager.sharedManager.activeReservation.firfullName = dictionary["fullname"] as? String
        // This will fire after the value in FBOSelector is read
        print("DELAYED SETTER")
        self.performSegue(identifier: segueId, 
       sender: self)
        print(RegistrationsManager.sharedManager.activeReservation.firfullName)
    }
})
}
```